# Как решить проблему в Google Pagespeed - Минимизируйте работу в основном потоке 3,2 сек.?

Tags: site

Всем привет! Оптимизирую на данный момент свой сайт [hdfilms.pro](https://hdfilms.pro), но никак не получается решить проблему, которую вы видите на скрине. [image: скрин]. Незнаю что делать, подскажите как улучшить скорость сайта? Уже разное перепробовал :( Никак не получается минимизировать(

Comment: Надо не минимизировать, а упрощать. Брать профайлер, анализировать и выкидывать лишний хлам из скриптов. Например, карусель, которая жрёт очень дохрена

Comment: спасибо большое, попробую!

Comment: Вот статья с рекомендациями почитайте: https://habr.com/ru/articles/436966/